# Biopython Entrez efetch

Tags: python

My code gives this error:

```
File "Entrez.py", line 16, in <module>
    record = Entrez.read (handle2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 454, in read
    record = handler.read(handle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 248, in read
    raise NotXMLError(e)
Bio.Entrez.Parser.NotXMLError: Failed to parse the XML data (syntax error: line 1, column 0). Please make sure that the input data are in XML format
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "shayezkarimcide@gmail.com"

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pmc", term = "Antimicrobial resistance",rettype = "medline",retmode = "xml",retmax= "10",sort = "pub date")

result = Entrez.read(handle)

Id = result ['IdList']

handle.close()

for val in Id :

    handle2 = Entrez.efetch(db="pmc", id=val, rettype="abstract", retmode="text")
    record = Entrez.read (handle2)

    print (record)
    handle2.close()
```

Comment: Which one do you want to get, XML or text? If XML, do you want it to be parsed?

Answer (score 0):

It's right in the error message: The parser doesn't think your input is valid XML. Either whatever `Entrez.efetch(...)` returns is not XML, or it has some other problem, like a data type mismatch with its DTD. I would start by printing or dumping to file the return value of `efetch` and seeing what's actually in there.